# Solr: Is re-indexing is must for stop-words?

Tags: solr

Does Solr 4.10.3 eliminates stop-words from query phrase if we add the stop-words in the stopwords.txt file without re-indexing the documents? Or documents re-indexing is must?

Because i added the stopwords (without re-indexing the documents) and solr still gives me result without eliminating the stopwords.

I've restarted the solr after adding the list in stopwords.txt file

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
<similarity class="solr.DFRSimilarityFactory">
        <str name="basicModel">I(F)</str>
        <str name="afterEffect">B</str>
        <str name="normalization">H2</str>
    </similarity>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
                 <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: field content is stored thats why u get whole data. when u use stopwords list, it doesn't remove stopwords from your data instead it wont index stopwords.

Comment: Well i think query analyzer remove key words from our query string so it wont search stopwords that is why there is a stopword filter their but i am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

consider query q=Iron man of India

if you use stopwords in your query analyzer and say word `of` is included in stopword list. solr will separate tokens as below

```
Iron, man, of, India
```

Since you used stopwords filter, it will discard word `"of"` and it will search for documents which has tokens(Iron, man, India). results documents Score depends on various factors like how many tokens present in doc, how times it is present(tf-IDF score)

It is same when you use stopwords during indexing.
it will index tokens (Iron, man, India) it will not index (of).